# Xcode & C/C++ project

Tags: c++, c, xcode

I want to use Xcode for C/C++ project.
I don't care about build/compilation, all i want is to use it as editor.
Needs:
 - Find symobol , References , callers etc

I've opened a console project, i can search for a symbol in the same file but nothing else. (for example, right click + jump to definition gives me a question mark ('?').

Any pointer to what needs to be done ?

Thanks,
Shaul.

Comment: Are you mixing C and C++ languages or using only one of them?

Comment: You may need to *build* the project so that XCode can create a table of the symbols and their locations in files.

Comment: Most of the files are in C but have some gtests that are C++

Comment: This is a Linux project so i assume (if the code isn't portable) I couldn't build it in Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

When adding files to the Xcode project,  on the bottom , need to click 'Options' and then choose 'Create groups' instead 'Create folder references'

This options will add all the sources and headers to 'Compile sources' and 'Headers' (Under 'Build Phases')

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, XCode is not designed to work well with C++. For example, you'll find that simple refactoring, such as renaming a function and automatically renaming usages, doesn't work well with XCode. I find AppCode works a lot better for (Obj)C++ development. Worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Thare are two approches

1. You need to create a library of your c++ project and add that library in your project
2. Add C++ project in your xcode and make it build as target source

let me now if you need a walkthrough